# How to display date as 19670805000000+1000

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, datetime

I am using Date format "yyyyMMddHHmmsszzz" but it displays the date as 19670805000000+10:00
where as I want date to be displayed as 19670805000000+1000

Could anyone please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ways to sort it out:

You could try using ['zz'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#zzSpecifier) and then add two zeros '00' to the end of the result if it doesn't end in 00 already or if it ends in +00 or -00 already.

Or

You could replace the ":" in the output with nothing "".

Or

Use to the [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the date value you have to append the offset manually to the string by taking its hours and minutes and appending it.